# Triple-boot - Ubuntu/Windows showing up but not Red Hat

Tags: grub2, windows-7, dual-boot

I installed triple boot Windows 7, Red Hat 5.5, and Ubuntu, but it's not showing Red Hat. It only shows Windows 7 and Ubuntu at booting time.

Can you please hep me out?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you update your question to include system specs, especially what boot manager you are using.

Comment: @nbm You mean boot-loader? Its tagged [tag:grub2].

Comment: Try `sudo update-grub` from Ubuntu. Then, reboot.

Comment: Yes, GRUB is a boot loader and boot manager.  However, I triple-boot on a Mactel and I find that using a separate boot manager (rEFInd) makes switching between OS a lot easier.  The OP doesn't mention any problems on install, only not seeing the Red Hat option at startup; a separate boot manager (on top of GRUB) might help with this.  But I'm not familiar with triple-booting on DOS boxes, so maybe not.  Hopefully the suggestion to simply update grub will work.

Answer (score 0):

If RedHat installed with LVM you need to install the lvm2 drivers in Ubuntu and mount the RedHat partition before running sudo update-grub.

```
sudo apt-get install lvm2
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a boot entry for your RedHat partition by editing `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file on Ubuntu.
The run the command `sudo update-grub`.